# Filter RavenDB query by entries of list

Tags: python, date, indexing, ravendb, raven

I am working with the python client for ravendb

My goal is to select unique `Types` and their `TypeCount` in a certain range of `DateTime`

Currently I have the following Map and Reduce:
[image]

and this gives me the following results:
[image]

Now I want to be able to select this in a certain `DateTime` range. For example, if we only take the `BTE` type into account, if I would say something along the lines of `where Dates > "2020-02-09"`, I'd want to get the following results:
`Type = BTE, TypeCount = 2, Dates = ["2020-02-09T00:50:07.0000890", "2020-02-09T00:59:41.0000210"`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by removing the Reduce part of the index and change `Dates` to `Date = pds.DateTime`, then you can query the index like this:

```
var queryResult = session.Query<Index.Result, Index>()
                        .Where(x => x.Type == "BTE" && x.Date > new DateTime(2020, 2, 9))
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I don't think this is the answer I was looking for. I wanted to use a reduced index to reduce the query time. If I see this correctly, I'd be using a normal index with your solution and kind of would be back to square 1.